# Combining ContainerEq and DoubleEq matchers in gtest

Tags: googletest

Is there a way to assert double values of containers in gtest using `DoubleNear` matcher?
There is also a `CombiningMatcher<T>` in the codebase but I cannot crack how to use it.

For example I would like to achieve something like that:

```
std::array<double, 2> expected{1.23, 2.34};
std::array<double, 2> results{1.231, 2.341};
ASSERT_THAT(results, ContainerEq(DoubleNear(expected, 1e-3)));
```

Where for each container item a `DoubleNear` is applied.

Another way would be to use `PointWise` matcher, which would work like:
`ASSERT_THAT(results, Pointwise(DoubleNear(1e-3), expected));`

Googletest version 1.10 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way in gtest 1.10 to directly use container matcher with floating point matcher (though it sounds like a reasonable feature request). For now you can define your own container matcher that takes abs err as an additional argument and internally compares container elements using `testing::DoubleNear` matcher:

```
MATCHER_P2(ContainerDoubleNear, container, abs_err, "")
{
    if (container.size() != arg.size()) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!::testing::ExplainMatchResult(::testing::DoubleNear(arg[i], abs_err), container[i], result_listener))
        {
            *result_listener << " for element at idx " << i;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can then use it like that:

```
EXPECT_THAT(expected, ContainerDoubleNear(results, ABS_ERR));
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qsa7jzjbh), diagnostic message might be slightly improved.

Comment: Thank you. With example of custom matcher.